# I'm Confused. How and when is using Object as argument and parameter useful in Java OOP?

Tags: java, oop

Hey guys I know this is kinda simple but it really confuses me.

I have here a simple code that computes for a Box's volume... that method is fine with me...

but I came across a topic that says you can use an object as a parameter so I tried it out.

Although this file compiles well I really don't get the point of having an object as a parameter. I just made this boolean method up but I really didn't understand what happened here.

How and when do we use an object as a parameter and/or as an argument?

```
class Box {
    private double width;
    private double height;
    private double length;

    public Box (double width, double height, double length) {
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
        this.length = length;
    }

    public double getVolume() {
        double volume = width * height * length;
        return volume;
    }

    public boolean testObject(Box a) { //I just made this up but how is it useful?
        if (a.width == width) {
            return true;
        } else return false;
    }
}


public class TestDrive {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Box b1 = new Box (8, 5, 10);

        System.out.println("b1 volume is = " + b1.getVolume());

        System.out.println(b1.testObject(b1)); // I don't know how this works
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To better understand it rename the method to `isEquallyWide` which fits your code.
Then it makes sense that `b1.isEquallyWide(b1)` returns true since `b1` is as wide as itself. In general passing in an object to a method on the same object does not make much sense (there may be *some* use cases)

On the other hand, creating a second box `Box b2 = new Box (999, 5, 10);` and then calling `b1.isEquallyWide(b2)` returns false because the boxes are not equally wide. The same goes for `b2.isEquallyWide(b1)`. `isEquallyWide` is commutative since it returns the same value in both cases.

If you would create a method `isWiderThan` then `b1.isWiderThan(b1)` will return false, `b1.isWiderThan(b2)` will return false as well but `b2.isWiderThan(b1)` will return true, this method is no longer commutative. In that case there is a difference in behaviour depending on which object you pass in and on which object you call the method.

Comment: Thanks for that luk2302. Any other ways in which using objects as parameters/arguments will become helpful in oop? :)

Comment: @Arcee yes, in basically *every* other way. When you create an instance of a Student and you want to persist that instance, then you pass that instance to the `insert` method of some database object. If you want to format a `Date` you pass it into a `DateFormatter` and get a string representation back. Really passing objects around is the basic principle of oop. *If* your `Box` would have a `name` property you would pass a `String` object into the constructor to specify that name, etc.

Comment: thanks man. I think I need to just practice applying this principle until I get the hang of it. At this point it's just hard to get a grip of everything if you're a newbie.

Answer (score 1):

There can be multiple use cases like comparing 2 objects, copying some fields from an existing object to a new object or applying some processing on the passed object and saving the result in the first object.

Here, for instance, your method testObject is comparing the width of the 2 objects. This you could have done by just passing the width as well. But think of a scenario when your object has 20+ fields and for comparing you need to compare multiple such fields. In such cases, passing individual fields instead of the entire object will be tiresome and non-intuitive.

Also, I am not sure if you know about copy constructor. Read about it, in case you have not.

Comment: Thanks thrust. That helped. May I know what we mean when we say "field"?

Comment: I meant data members of the class when I said 'fields'

Answer (score 1):

```
public boolean testObject(Box a) { //I just made this up but how is it 
           useful?
    if (a.width == width){
        return true;
    }else return false;
}
```

Here you have a method testObject to compare other Box object reference with the current one. The advantage is that, once you have the whole object as a parameter then you can extend the comparison logic (in your case you have only width now, but later point of time it can be width and height also) easily without changing the method signature. Hope it is clear.